# [Vue warn]: Property or method is not defined ... but it is. Right here

Tags: javascript, properties, vuejs2

I'm struggling with this stupid bug in Vuejs. `showMenu` is defined in `computed`. The store has the right value as well.

Apparently if I remove the following from `Header.vue`, the console is clear from errors. But, I've always worked like that and this is the first time I have this error.

```
<script src="./header.js"></script>
<style src="./header.scss" lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "showMenu" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from '@/router';
import { store } from '@vue/store/index.js';
import i18n from '@vue/i18n.js'
import App from '@vue/components/App.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;


new Vue({
    store,
    i18n,
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount(`#app`);
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-if="showMenu"><app-header></app-header></div>
        <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="./App.js"></script>
<style src="./App.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

App.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppHeader from '@vue/components/app/header/Header.vue';

export default {
    name: `App`,
    components: {
        AppHeader,
    },
    data() { return {

    }},
    computed : {
        showMenu(){ return this.$store.state.ui.showMenu; }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just removing the `script` tag in `Header.vue` removes the error.

1- I need the JS in `Header.vue`
2- ?? Why a component is making the parent having an error on its props?

Comment: Show `/header.js` then.

Comment: There is nothing in it. 

```
<template>
 <header class="header">
           Nav + Logo test
 </header>
</template>

<script src="./header.js"></script>
<style src="./header.scss" lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

`header.scss` is empty and `header.js` only has `export default {name='AppHeader'}`

It feels like vue-loader doesn't load separate files.

Comment: @spyesx did you solve this issue?